Where did EmbeddedMongoProperties go? (Spring-boot 1.5.2.RELEASE -> 3.1.0)
I'm currently trying to migrate a MongoDB project I'm working on from spring-boot 1.5.2.RELEASE to 3.1.0, and I can't seem to find the EmbeddedMongoProperties class (Found in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.embedded) anywhere in the library. Looking around on the docs.spring.io documentation hasn't given me any answer as to when it was deprecated, or what it got replaced with. Is there an equivalent to it that can be used or did its functions get moved to something else?
